# Error generating model in SQL Server 2022 Reporting Services for a data source with an SSAS connection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2022

The application currently runs on SQL Server 2014 and looking to migrate to SQL Server 2022.  We are trying to generate a model from a data source in SSRS using Powershell, but it is failing with the following error: "System.ArgumentException: The connection cannot be recognized as a connection to Analysis Services Server."

```
$url = "https://localhost/ReportServer_NamedInstance/reportservice2010.asmx?WSDL"
$ssrs = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $url -UseDefaultCredential

#create data source 
$dataSourceDefinitionType = ($type + '.DataSourceDefinition');
$dataSourceDefinition = new-object ($dataSourceDefinitionType);
$dataSourceDefinition.Extension = "OLEDB-MD"
$dataSourceDefinition.ConnectString = "Data Source=localhost\NamedInstance; Initial Catalog=SAMPLE_DB_OLAP"
$dataSourceDefinition.CredentialRetrieval = 'Integrated'
$newDataSource = $ssrs.CreateDataSource("SAMPLE_DB_OLAP", "/", $true, $dataSourceDefinition, $null);
    
# create model
$warnings = @()
$dataSourceName = "/SAMPLE_DB_OLAP"
$ssrs.GenerateModel("SAMPLE_DB_OLAP", "SampleDbOlapModel", "/", $null, [ref] $warnings)
```

The full error shown is:

```
Exception calling "GenerateModel" with "5" argument(s): "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error occurred while generating model. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ModelGenerationErrorException: An error occurred while generating model. --->
System.ArgumentException: The connection cannot be recognized as a connection to Analysis Services Server.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.GenerateModel(String DataSource, String Model, String Parent, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.GenerateModel(String DataSource, String Model, String Parent, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)"
At line:1 char:1
+ $ssrs.GenerateModel("...)
```

We have tried:

1. Generating a model from a data source that points to a database (not SSAS/OLAP) and the command works successfully.
2. Updating the connection string to specify a provider (e.g. Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=localhost\NamedInstancel Initial Catalog=SAMPLE_DB_OLAP) but no variation seems to get SSRS to identify the connection as a connection to Analysis Services Server.
3. Decompiled the DLLs with dotPeek to identify where the error was coming from, but this did not provide any leads.  The method that appears to be throwing the error is basically "return connection is AdomdConnection ? connection as AdomdConnection : throw new ArgumentException(....)"

Has anyone had luck generating a model for an SSAS data source in SQL Server 2022?

Comment: How and where do you define `$type`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Forgot to include that line in the snippet: `$type = $ssrs.GetType().Namespace;` is right below the `$ssrs` variable initialization